# Help for calculating Area Using Double Integral

Tags: definite-integrals

**I am trying to solve this problem. I would appreciate if someone can check if my approach is correct.

**Problem:**

D is the plane region defined by: 
$$x^2+y^2-2x \le0\ and\ y\le |x|   $$

$a)\ Calculate\ the\ Area\ D$ 
$(b)\ Evaluate$ $$\iint_D \frac{|y|}{x^2+y^2} \,\mathrm dxdy$$

**SOLUTION**
$$Intersection\ of\ the\ two\ functions\ gives\ Points\ (0,0)\ and\ (1,1)$$
$$x^2+y^2-2x\le 0 => (x=1)^2 +y^2 \le1\ which \ is\ a\ circle\ with\ radius \ and\ centre\ (1,0)$$
$$\begin{align}\text{Area }A&=\iint_D \,\mathrm dA\qquad\qquad \mathrm dA=r\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta\\&=\int_0^\frac{3\pi}4\int_0^{2cos\theta}r\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta\\&=\int_0^\frac{3\pi}4\left[\frac{r^2}2\right]_0^{2cos\theta}\,\mathrm d\theta\\&=\left[\frac{3\pi -2}4\right]\end{align}$$

(b) using the limits $\frac{-\pi}{2} to \frac{\pi}{4} $
$$\iint_D \frac{|y|}{x^2+y^2} \,\mathrm dxdy =\int_\frac{-\pi}2^\frac{\pi}4\int_0^{2cos\theta}\frac{rsin\theta}{r^2}r \,\mathrm drd\theta\ $$

$$\iint_D \frac{|y|}{x^2+y^2} \,\mathrm dxdy =\int_\frac{-\pi}2^\frac{\pi}4\int_0^{2cos\theta}\sin\theta \,\mathrm drd\theta\ $$

$$\iint_D \frac{|y|}{x^2+y^2} \,\mathrm dxdy =-\frac{1}{2} $$

Comment: Why it was downvoted? MathJaX is not perfect, but the try is valuable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Working to check the solution:

$$\frac34 \cdot \pi \cdot 1^2 + \frac12 \cdot 1^2 $$

should be the correct answer as that is the area of $\frac34$ of the circle plus the area of a triangle.

Your mistake is the range of the angle:

The angle should be from $-\frac{\pi}2$ to $\frac{\pi}4$,

\begin{align}&\int_{-\frac{\pi}2}^\frac{\pi}4 2 \cos^2 \theta \, d\theta \\
&=\int_{-\frac{\pi}2}^\frac{\pi}4  \cos (2\theta)+1 \, d\theta \\
&= \frac{ \sin (2\theta)}{2}+\theta \mid_{-\frac{\pi}2}^\frac{\pi}4\\
&=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{3\pi}{4}\end{align}

Edit:

\begin{align}
\int_{-\frac{\pi}2}^{\frac{\pi}4} \int_0^{2\cos\theta} \frac{r|\sin \theta|}{r^2} \cdot r\, \, dr d\theta &= \int_{-\frac{\pi}2}^{\frac{\pi}4} \int_0^{2\cos\theta} |\sin \theta|\, \, dr d\theta \\
&= \int_{-\frac{\pi}2}^{\frac{\pi}4} 2\cos\theta|\sin \theta|\, d\theta \\
&=  \int_{-\frac{\pi}2}^{0} 2\cos\theta|\sin \theta|\, d\theta +\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}4} 2\cos\theta|\sin \theta|\, d\theta  \\
&= -\int_{-\frac{\pi}2}^{0} 2\cos\theta\sin \theta\, d\theta +\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}4} 2\cos\theta\sin \theta\, d\theta  \\
\end{align}

Comment: +1. Nice explanation of the expected value, modulo area of the *circle*. :-)

Comment: @ Siong, Thank you very much. The part (a) is now solved. I wish to find out if my approach for part (b) is correct.

Comment: the answer can't be negative since we are integrating a nonnegative term.

Comment: @Siong, In that case can I use |y| = -y?

Comment: edited my answer, well, $|y|=-y$ sometimes but not all the times, we have to consider cases.